# Добавить данные во все контроллеры

Tags: php, события, symfony, request

Дано: **n**-ное количество контроллеров и переменная, которая тянется сервисом из базы данных, и которая нужна всем этим контроллерам.

Суть вопроса: как "прокинуть" переменную во все контроллеры, не прокидывая каждый раз в них сервис.

**Пример контроллера**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Knp\Component\Pager\PaginatorInterface;
...

class FooController extends AbstractController
{
    private $doctrine;
    private $paginator;

    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $doctrine, PaginatorInterface $paginator)
    {
        ...
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/foo", name="foo")
     */
    public function index(Request $request): Response
    {
        $qb = $this->doctrine->getRepository(Foo::class)->function();
    
        $page = $request->query->get('aaa', 1);
    
        ...
    
        return $this->render('default/foo.twig', [

        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/foo/{url}", name="foo_bar")
     */
    public function fooBar(Request $request, string $baz): Response
    {
        $co = new Co();
        $foo = $this->doctrine->getRepository(Co::class)->function(['baz' => $baz]);
        ...
    
        return $this->renderForm('aaa/foo_bar.twig', [

        ]);
}
```

}

**Пример сервиса**

```
<?php

namespace App\Servise;

use App\Repository\FooRepository;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class FooServise
{
    private $foo;
    private $bar;
    private $baz;

    public function __construct(FooRepository $repository, ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->foo = $repository;
        $this->bar = $repository->findAll();
        $this->baz = current(array_filter(
            $this->bar,
            function($bar)
            {
                return $bar->getName() === 'aaaaa';
            }))->getValue();
    }

    ...

    public function Bar(): string
    {
        return $this->baz;
    }

    ...


}
```

Так вот. Можно ли как-то "прокинуть" **baz** переменную сразу во все контроллеры? Подключать в каждый контроллер сервис не хочется.
Подкиньте идеи, будьте добры

**UPDATE**

Переменная нужна не для вывода в шаблоны, а для использования внутри контроллеров. Копаю в сторону *EventSubscriber*, но как-то застрял на месте, как бы такое реализовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Накопал в документации [Creating an Event Listener](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/components/http_kernel.html#creating-an-event-listener)

Глянул таблицу, оказалось, что копать нужно было не в сторону RequestEvent, а в сторону KernelEvent. Навесил EventSubscriber на событие ядра:

```
<?php

namespace App\EventSubscriber;


use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\KernelEvent;
use App\Servise\FooServise;

class KernelEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $foo;
    
    public function __construct(FooServise $foo)
    {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(KernelEvent $event)
    {
        $event->getRequest()->request->add(['baz' => $this->foo->Bar()]);
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'kernel.request' => 'onKernelRequest',
        ];
    }
}
```

Теперь получаем в контроллере переменную через Request:

```
$request->request->get('baz');
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно что это самое хорошее решение. Я бы не стал закидывать в request кастомный параметр, мы ведь ожидаем в request то что к нам приходит, простите, в реквесте, а тут мы имеем магию в виде baz... и не говоря о том что в момент когда все об этом забудбут, кто то будет удивлятся почему baz из реквеста какой то постоянно не тот.

Ну и даже если вы решили всю свою бизнес логику и работу с БД выполнять в контроллере, то вам скорее стоит присмотреться все же к
https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/argument_value_resolver.html
кастомному резолверу. И то у меня большие сомнения верно ли вы выстроили работу с данными архитектурно, ведь

> Переменная нужна не для вывода в шаблоны, а для использования внутри контроллеров.

немного сбивает с толку. Если вам для работы контроллера нужны данные завязаны на данных из базы данных, то очень большой риск что вы контроллер используете не совсем по назначению.

Comment: Дело в том, что в данный момент первостепенная задача - запуститься. То, что архитектурно это не _совсем_ верное решение - это я осознаю.
Контроллер используется по назначению, только логика отдачи View - завязана на БД (пути к шаблонам). В переменной - путь к ним

Comment: Т.е. обращение к View строиться таким образом:
return $this->render(**$baz** . '/template_name.html.twig', [
        ]);
И эта $baz переменная - хранится в БД